# Node.js Undefined CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, eclipse

I just created a default Node.js Express Project. The index.ejs file is giving me the error:

Undefined CSS file ('/stylesheets/style.css').

Here is the index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I think is the relevant code from the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The directory structure looks like this:

[image]

To my understanding, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` should allow me to reference the relative directory `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />`, but I am still getting the undefined css error. What is wrong?

EDIT: Here is my current configuration:

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('public', __dirname + '/public');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static('public'));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) { // jshint ignore:line
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.render('index.ejs'); });

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an eclipse bug. The style.css is actually being read by the page in spite of the error showing in index.ejs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

or

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Express documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Edit 1:

You have an extra '/'

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css' />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither seems to resolve the error. I also tried `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/stylesheet')));`, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheet')));`, `app.use(express.static('public/stylesheet'));`, and `app.use(express.static('/public/stylesheet'));` with no luck.

Comment: check my changes below Edit1:

Comment: I tried removing the leading /, but still have the error. I also tried adding `app.set('public', __dirname + '/public');` to app.js, but that did not help.

Comment: Do you have this :

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('index.ejs');
    });

somewhere in your app.js

Comment: The closest I have is the line, `app.get('/', routes.index);`. I added your line, but the error persists.

Comment: I updated the current state of both files in my original post.

Comment: Are you seeing anything when you navigate to your localhost ?

Comment: Yes, the page is responding. Now that I looked into it, it is reading the CSS. I changed the text color to red in the style.css & it changed it on the page. So sorry, this seems to be an eclipse bug...